# Trim the ID column of a recurring event to just display the start date in my calculated field

Tags: recurring-events

I want to create a calculated column to trim the value in the ID column of a recurring event.

Non-recurring event ID 7
Recurring Event ID 6.0.2014-06-06T18:00:00Z

Notice the date of this recurring event is 2014-06-06.  That is what I need and then convert the date to be the format of (TODAY)

Thanks,
Rhonda

Comment: Please tag your post with the programming language you are inquiring about.

Comment: This is for SharePoint 2010 on a calendar list